# Maximum amount of class members

Tags: class, vb6

Sometime I am in need to create classes with quite a high amount of members. What I notice is that the higher the amount of members is, the more fro my PF (Page File) IS USED (NOT RAM). But the real problem comes when I need to destroy the class and free up the memory. It takes too much time, and what also is a problem, during this time the application stops to respond. I tried to remove the class members one by one, setting them =nothing, but the result is quite the same.

Comment: How many variables do you define in a class? And what data types do they have?

Comment: The data types are mostly numeric- Interegr, Double. The amount is really signifficant- up to 1,000,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a game utility of sorts that had large object graphs that, when a game was closed to open a new one, exhibited quite a delay due to the object cleanup.  What I did was to have a disposal manager of sorts.  The objects that needed to be cleaned up where passed to the disposal manager and then the application went about its business of creating and using new objects.  Behind the scenes on a timer the disposal manager would walk the object graph of the discarded tree and free them a few hundred per Tick.  It would take up to 15 seconds before everything was cleaned up this way, but the user was unaware and application performance was unaffected.